# Should we rename the blender-internal tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm constantly seeing the [blender-internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-internal) tag (somewhat understandably) misused for questions about the way blender handles things internally. E.g. like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/28197/revisions).

Should we rename this tag to avoid confusion? Or would this only create more confusion?

Comment: Rename it to what?

Comment: Maybe `blender-render`? I really prefer to call it blender internal though, as it seems everyone else says BI or blender internal render.. Perhaps `internal-render`? idk

Comment: Can you list at least half a dozen questions that occurred within this or last month? If not, I don't see it as a huge deal for the most part. We do have a disclaimer on it that it's to be used for the engine only but I guess people don't read. `blender-render` or `internal-render` could work as well since that's what it's labelled.

Comment: @iKlsR I tried to find more examples but it's not the easiest thing to search for..

Comment: Same but it's better to stamp out minor quirks like this as it is a fairly popular tag.

Comment: @iKlsR now having a tag "blender-render" may lead to yet more miss use. Anything that gets rendered with blender, regardless of the render engine, could foreseeably be tagged "blender-render" (by the same type of people that missed used "blender-internal").

Comment: @David Let's watch it for a while and see. I was for `blender-internal-render` but I think that's too long.

Comment: @iKlsR agreed, on both points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree it is misleading to an extent. [blender-render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-render) is a good rename/synonym since that's what it is labelled inside Blender. I went ahead and merged these and also added [internal-render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-render) as a synonym as well. This should no doubt prevent any future accidental use.