# Should duplicate and paid add-on tags be kept or removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

While reading through questions, I realized that there are a great number of tags that seem to be either duplicated or otherwise very sparsely used or just misused frequently.

Would it be useful to either consolidate or remove some of these? It might make edits and asking a bit simpler, but I would be interested to hear feedback.The list of tags is below.

---

[auto-rig-pro](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-rig-pro)

[select](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select)

[bytes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bytes)

[archipack-add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archipack-add-on)

[addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addon) **not** [add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-on)

[alpha](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha) **not** [alpha-channel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha-channel)

[blender-internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-internal) **and**[internal-render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-render)**and**[blender-internal-render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-internal-render) **and** [blender-render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-render) **and** [render-engine-blender-internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/render-engine-blender-internal) **NOT** [blender-internal-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-internal-render-engine) <sub>*(or something, this one is maybe a little confusing, although with 2.8 soon a non-issue I guess)*</sub>

[eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eevee) **and** [render-engine-eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/render-engine-eevee) **NOT** [eevee-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eevee-render-engine)

[fcurve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fcurve) **NOT** [fcurves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fcurves)

[luxrender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luxrender) **and** [render-engine-luxrender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/render-engine-luxrender) **NOT** [luxrender-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luxrender-render-engine)

[math](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) **and**[maths](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths) **NOT** [mathematics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics)

[modelling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modelling) **NOT** [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling)

[renderman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renderman) **and**[render-engine-renderman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/render-engine-renderman) **NOT** [renderman-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renderman-render-engine)

[sss](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sss) **NOT** [subsurface-scattering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsurface-scattering)

Comment: A lot of those are [synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) and not duplicates. They redirect to the 'primary' tag. Bytes was created by a new user, removed by me, and will automatically be deleted soon. There are also discussions [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/what-can-we-do-to-reduce-the-misuse-of-the-blender-render-tag) and [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/revamping-tags-2020) about tags.

Comment: Hi Timaroberts, thanks for the investigation. Like Ray said most of those are already [synonyms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) if you follow the links they'll take you to the correct targets. The ones that aren't were possibly overlooked and will be merged

Comment: I guess I had assumed that they were just duplicated, especially with all of the BI tags :) thanks for the clarification!

Comment: [BSE tag synonyms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)

Comment: @David thanks! I didn't know that page existed :)